# How to Sum values by day and group in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sum

i have the following table:

| date | value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-07 00:00:00 | 5 | a |
| 2021-04-07 00:00:00 | 10 | b |
| 2021-04-07 01:00:00 | 5 | a |
| 2021-04-07 01:00:00 | 4 | b |
| 2021-04-08 00:00:00 | 5 | a |
| 2021-04-08 00:00:00 | 8 | b |
| 2021-04-08 01:00:00 | 4 | a |
| 2021-04-08 01:00:00 | 5 | b |

And i want to know how could i sum the values by day and group, like this:

| date | total_value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-07 | 10 | a |
| 2021-04-07 | 14 | b |
| 2021-04-08 | 9 | a |
| 2021-04-08 | 13 | b |

Hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the aggregate function `sum` and grouping by `date` and `group` will achieve this. Since you have timestamp data, the solution below casts it to a `date` type and groups using that. Finally in the projection, I also casted to a `text` to remove the additional date information and just provide with `YYYY-MM-DD`

**Schema (PostgreSQL v11)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  "date" TIMESTAMP,
  "value" INTEGER,
  "Group" VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  ("date", "value", "Group")
VALUES
  ('2021-04-07 00:00:00', '5', 'a'),
  ('2021-04-07 00:00:00', '10', 'b'),
  ('2021-04-07 01:00:00', '5', 'a'),
  ('2021-04-07 01:00:00', '4', 'b'),
  ('2021-04-08 00:00:00', '5', 'a'),
  ('2021-04-08 00:00:00', '8', 'b'),
  ('2021-04-08 01:00:00', '4', 'a'),
  ('2021-04-08 01:00:00', '5', 'b');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select
   "date"::date::text,
   sum(value) as total_value,
   "Group"
FROM
   my_table
GROUP BY
   "date"::date, "Group";
```

| date | total_value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-07 | 10 | a |
| 2021-04-07 | 14 | b |
| 2021-04-08 | 9 | a |
| 2021-04-08 | 13 | b |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sJrMtmuAhj1rfo7RipffHN/1)